# ChartJS align bars to left instead of center

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a relatively simple bar chart in my application.

[image]

Code:

```js
    new Chart(document.getElementById("foo"), {
        type: "bar",
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    display: false,
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    display: false,
                }]
            },
            elements: {
                bar: {
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: "#D2DDEC"
                },
                point: {
                    hoverRadius: 0
                },
            },
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
        },
        data: {
            labels: Object.keys(values),
            datasets: [{
                data: Object.values(values),
            }]
        }
    })
```

However, these bars will center in the middle of the container, while I would like these to start left.
Is there a way to do this? I don't see any `align` property in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added labels until I reached 31. fixed.